# Using to delete

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I need to Write a ‘sed’ command that would delete the first field from every line of a file (that is, everything up to and including the first spaces in the line.)

I think it should look something like this but I'm not quite sure:

```
sed '^[^:]*/d file
```

Comment: Could you please post some example, I mean the **input data** and the **expected result**?

Answer (score 2):

In `sed` /d means delete. Your code will delete lines that match the `regex`.

```
sed 's/^[^ ]* //g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^\S+\s+//' file
```

This removes the first non-space(s) followed by space(s).

Answer (score 0):

`d` command in `sed` deletes the whole line.

You need to use `s` command like this:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^[^ ]* //' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by spaces you mean, you want to remove the entirety of the first block of whitespace and everything proceeding it. In which case do something like

```
sed 's/^\w*[ \t]*//' file.txt
```

e.g.

```
$ printf "string1 \t  string2\n\tstring3 string4\n"
string1       string2
    string3 string4
$ printf "string1 \t  string2\n\tstring3 string4\n" | sed 's/^\w*[ \t]*//'
string2
string3 string4
```